# Removal of whitespace and text in brackets - make my working code more elegant

Tags: regex, python-2.7, replace, brackets

I wrote a code to remove all parentheses in a txt file, and the text between them, as well as multiple whitespace.

However, I have very little experience with Python, and it's quite obvious that my code is inefficient.

What's the best way to do what I want?

```
import re

lines = open('test.txt', 'r+')
lines = [re.sub('\s+',' ', line) for line in lines] #this is to kill 'tab' whitespaces
lines = [re.sub(' +',' ', line) for line in lines] #regular whitespace, if more than 1
lines = [re.sub('\(.*?\)','', line) for line in lines] #brackets and the text
with open('test2.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: The second re.sub is useless, since `\s` matches spaces too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough lines to offset the cost of compiling the regexes, something like the following should serve.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lines = {' foo      (bar)    '}
    parens_regex = re.compile(r'\(.*?\)')  # Non-greedy
    space_regex =  re.compile(r'\s+')

    for line in lines:
        print 'Before: "%s"' % line
        line_tmp = parens_regex.sub('', line)  # Before space-regex so we also collapse space around parens
        line_tmp = space_regex.sub(' ', line_tmp)
        line_tmp = line_tmp.strip()
        print 'After: "%s"' % line_tmp  # Prints: "foo"
```

I guess it's questionable whether that's more elegant - probably not.
You already knew enough about regexes to make your parens regex non-greedy.
But maybe a future Stack Overflow reader doesn't. Or maybe they or you didn't know about compiling regexes...

Comment: Thanks! But actually I don't think I know enough about of regexes, hehe. What does it mean exactly when it's non-greedy?

Comment: In `\(.*\)`, the `.*` is greedy - it will consume as much of the input as possible, while still satisfying the rest of the regex. So if your input string is, for example, `(foo(bar)(baz))`, the `.*` will match `foo(bar)(baz)`. On the other hand, you can make the quantifier non-greedy (by sticking a `?` on the end in Python): `.*?`, which makes it consume as *little* of the input string as possible while still satisying the constraints of the regex as a whole. So `\(.*?\)`, run against the above input, would match on `(foo(bar)` - basically everything between the first `(` and the *first* `)`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense and is very useful!